# How to npm config save into project .npmrc file?

Tags: npm

I am hoping to run `npm config` to set values in a project's .npmrc file. 
[Docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/config) dont seem to say how to specify a file to save the values into.

Looking for something like 
`npm config --file /path/to/repo/.npmrc set key value`

Trying to use it for a build script that needs to build a .npmrc file from env vars.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is baffling that this is seemingly still not directly supported as of npm v6.9.0.

It's a bit awkward, but if your npm version is recent enough, you can **repurpose the [`--userconfig` option](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config)** to make `npm config` operate on a *project-specific* `.npmrc` file.

E.g., from a given project's root folder, the following command project-locally configures `pwsh` (PowerShell Core) as the shell to run scripts with, by making `npm config` operate on the local `.npmrc` file via `--userconfig`:

```sh
# Updates .npmrc in current dir
npm config set script-shell pwsh --userconfig .npmrc
```

**Note**: As [Kerry Johnson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3266845/kerry-johnson) points out:

- The target file is rewritten as a whole, in the course of which any *comments* (`#`-prefixed lines) in the original file are *lost* (but all key-value pairs are preserved).
- The `config` keyword is optional in this case, so the following will do:

  ```
  npm set script-shell pwsh --userconfig .npmrc
  ```

Comment: As of `npm@8`, a new config option `-L, --location <global|user|project>` is provided which means you no longer have to specify a filename like `--userconfig` needs.  However `--userconfig <file>` still works.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a [`chroot`](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/chroot-practices.html), build  your config file on `~/.npmrc` and then copy it on the right location.

Comment: I like your creativity.

Comment: eh, but then if you run "npm config set thiskey thatvalue" it won't write to the same file. I don't even think when I run my project that it picks up the "per-package" .npmrc file.... :(

Answer (score 1):

you can override any property which could be set by the .npmrc
by passing it through command line.
For example `--package-lock false` will turn off package-lock generation.

Answer (score 0):

This has been supported since NPM version 7.

From the docs:

`location`

- Default: "user" unless --global is passed, which will also set this value to "global"
- Type: "global", "user", or **"project"**

When passed to npm config this refers to which config file to use.

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/commands/npm-config#location